# Error code Overflow and wildcard not working Excel VBA

Tags: overflow, wildcard

In the following code, I get an error at line pec1 = pec+1, in which is indicated to be some 30000 number. pec6, pec3, pec5 all also have numbers greater than 1000.

Also looking a little further down, when I do a wildcard search 72-41-* for the numbers like 72-41-00, 72-41-13, it gives a return value of 0.

Thank you so much for helping me.

*update: Please help me. Excel now stops running after I try to run the program. :(

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Dim egr As String, pec1 As Long, pec2 As Long, pec3 As Long
Dim pec4 As Long
Dim pec5 As Long
Dim pec6 As Long
Dim lastroww As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim h As Long
Dim om As String

egr = ""
pec1 = 0
pec2 = 0
pec3 = 0
pec4 = 0
pec5 = 0
pec6 = 0
dummy = 0
k = 4

With Sheet1
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A3:K3").AutoFilter
        .Range("A3:K3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="05.00 PEC"
    End With

With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
lastroww = lastrow - 3

Do Until Cells(k, 4).Value = ""
        For k = 4 To lastroww
            pm = Cells(k, 8).Value
            If pm = "" Then
                pec6 = pec6 + 1
                ElseIf pm = "Semais,June" Then
                    pec1 = pec1 + 1
                ElseIf pm = "Mwier,Robert" Then
                    pec3 = pec3 + 1
                ElseIf pm = "Newton,Sally" Then
                    pec5 = pec5 + 1
            End If
            om = Cells(k, 7).Value
            If om = "" Then
                ElseIf om = "72-41*" Then
                     pec2 = pec2 + 1
                ElseIf om = "72-51*" Or om = "72-52-*" Or om = "72-53-*" Then
                    pec4 = pec4 + 1
            End If
        Next k
Loop
```